# Create a column based on other columns value

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to create a new column with values based on the value in the first column, with the highest score in the same cluster.

The goal is to move from this:

```
WORD     | SCORE | Cluster |
diptyqu  | 19750 |    1    |
daptyqu  | 8830  |    1    |
dyptiqu  | 29    |    1    |
deptiqu  | 2     |    1    |
parfume  | 300   |    2    |
parfum   | 14    |    2    |
```

To this:

```
WORD     | SCORE | Cluster | Name    |
diptyqu  | 19750 |    1    | diptyqu |
daptyqu  | 8830  |    1    | diptyqu |
dyptiqu  | 29    |    1    | diptyqu |
deptiqu  | 2     |    1    | diptyqu |
parfume  | 300   |    2    | parfume |
parfum   | 14    |    2    | parfume |
```

I'm litteraly stuck and don't really know how to make it. Do you have any suggestion on a method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
your_data %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  mutate(Name = first(WORD))
```

It assumes your rows are already sorted by SCORE. If needed, you can do that sorting too:

```
your_data %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  arrange(desc(SCORE)) %>%
  mutate(Name = first(WORD))
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Similar strategy as in @Gregor's `dplyr` solution, but using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[order(SCORE), Name := tail(WORD, 1), Cluster]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(dat, dat$Cluster), function(a)
            data.frame(a, Name = a$WORD[which.max(a$SCORE)])))
#       WORD SCORE Cluster    Name
#1.1 diptyqu 19750       1 diptyqu
#1.2 daptyqu  8830       1 diptyqu
#1.3 dyptiqu    29       1 diptyqu
#1.4 deptiqu     2       1 diptyqu
#2.5 parfume   300       2 parfume
#2.6  parfum    14       2 parfume
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'data.table' packages and merge function:

```
    library(data.table)
    df2 <- setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(SCORE)], Cluster]
    result <- merge(df, df2[, c('Cluster', 'WORD')], by='Cluster')
```